# Customize remote notification received using react native firebase/

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am currently trying to customize the notification displayed in the react native Android application.

But I am bit confused between the remote notification and local notification. I know I can get the click handle from remote notification in `onNotificationOpened`. But I want to customize it the way it appears in the notification tray.